# Raspberry Pi: SenseHat cannot initialize sensors from web app

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, settings, uwsgi

Hello and thanks for reading my very first question!

I am trying to integrate the sensor data of a Sense HAT (former ASTRO PI) board into a webpage that I am hosting on a Raspberry Pi 4 with NGINX + uWSGI + Flask.
I had some problems since the user *www-data* could not access e.g. the /dev/fb1 device. I guess I fixed some of these issues by adding www-data to the *pi*, the *input*, the *gpio*, and the *video* user groups but in the uWSGI log I still get some exception, when I try to access/initialize the SenseHAT's humidity, temperature, or pressure:

```
[2020-04-28 11:15:55,904] ERROR in app: Exception on /system [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./web_base.py", line 35, in system
    temp_humidity = round(sense.get_temperature_from_humidity(),1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 582, in get_temperature_from_humidity
    self._init_humidity()  # Ensure humidity sensor is initialised
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 549, in _init_humidity
    raise OSError('Humidity Init Failed')
OSError: Humidity Init Failed
```

When I run this as the default user inside Thonny, it works, so I guess I still miss some group for my www-data user.

I am using the *CPUTemperature* object from *gpiozero*, too, to read the CPU temperature and this is working, only the sensors from *sense_hat* fail to init.

Does anybody out there have any idea what I am missing or give me a hint where to look at to find a solution?

Thank you very much.

HvFf

Comment: Same issue. Have you sorted it?

Comment: No, sorry. No solution, yet.